# pandas dataframe filter to return True for ALL rows. how?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Hi I have a filter 'm' set that is flexible enough to change by me. Sometimes, I want to filter by Car or x_acft_body , or any of the various other fields, etc. Sometime I want to have **all of the rows returned** by commenting and uncommenting the required lines. But without changing the subsequent code, after the filter 'm' line.

How can I have a filter that will return true for ALL rows, when I don't want the filters applied? For e.g. something like `1==1` but i know this doesn't work.

I don't want to set `dfdata.somefield.notnull()` etc.  as I will not be too sure if this field will be always not null or not. also I **DO NOT want to change subsequent code** to be like `dfdata.groupby.`     i.e. without the `[m]`

```
# set filter if needed
m = (   1==1 #& return true at all times
#         (dfdata.Car == 'PG') #&
#         (dfdata.x_acft_body == 'N')# &
#         (dfdata.Car.isin(['PG', 'VJ', 'VZ']))
)


dft1 = dfdata[m].groupby(['FLD1']).agg({'FLD2': 'count'})
```

Comment: Is not possible set `m = (True)` for return all rows?

Comment: that returns KeyError: True

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create bool constant and change final mask by it:

```
#True for return all rows
m = (dfdata.Car == 'PG') | True
```

And:

```
#False for apply filter
m = (dfdata.Car == 'PG') | False
```

---

First solutions:

```
m = [True] * len(df.index)
```

---

```
m = np.repeat(True, len(df.index))
```

Comment: ```#False for apply filter
m = (dfdata.Car == 'PG') | False``` <<<< This is redundant I think... do you mean to say ```m = (dfdata.Car == 'PG') & False``` ? only then it will return False all rows.

Comment: Yes, it is not necessary. If possible True or nothing, False can be omit.